# MouseDragElementBehavior Leaving duplicate item behind

Tags: c#, wpf, drag-and-drop

I am having a bit of a problem with the MouseDragElementBehvior in WPF. I am implementing a scrabble game with tiles that I want to drag from a rack onto the board (both of which are Canvas elements). The tiles are obviously different every time and are therefore generated in the code behind.

I managed to get the Drag behavior to work and I am able to drag images from the tile rack (Canvas) to another Canvas. The problem comes in when I have placed one on the board and wish to move it again. It works the first few times and then sometimes, when you drag an item that is already on the board, it leaves a duplicate of the item behind, and then throws a null reference exception.

The way I have implemented it is by having an global image variable that keeps track of which image is currently being dragged if there is one, and basically on the MouseDown event, I change the currently selected tile to the one that has just been pressed.

```
 MouseDragElementBehavior dragBe = new MouseDragElementBehavior();
 dragBe.Attach(imageIcon);
 dragBe.DragFinished += onDragFinishedFromBoard;                      
 imageIcon.MouseDown += (sender, args) =>
 {
 if (currentTileSelected ==null)
 {
        currentTileSelected = sender as Image;                              
 } };
```

Then the event that gets fired for the Drag finish:

```
    private void onDragFinishedFromBoard(object sender, MouseEventArgs args)
{
if (currentTileSelected != null)
        {
            s = (Square) currentTileSelected.Tag;
            letter = (Tile)s.Letter;

            double X = args.GetPosition(canvasBoard).X;
            double y = args.GetPosition(canvasBoard).Y;
            int row, col;
            if (X > 0 && y > 0)
            {

                row = (int)Math.Floor(y / 35);
                col = (int)Math.Floor(X / 35);
                if (theCurrentGame.TheBoard.ScrabbleBoard[col][row].ContainsLetter==true)
                {
                    //
                    currentTileSelected.Source = null;
                    currentTileSelected.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
                    currentTileSelected = null;
                    redrawTileRack();


                }
                else
                {
                    Debug.WriteLine("row: " + row + " col:" + col);
                    //remove it from old position
                    if (s!=null)
                    {
                        s.ContainsLetter = false;
                        s.Letter = null;
                        s.partOfCurrentTurn = false;
                        theCurrentGame.TheBoard.ScrabbleBoard[s.Coordinate.Key][s.Coordinate.Value] = s;

                    }
                   //snap it into board new position
                    Square currentSquare = theCurrentGame.TheBoard.ScrabbleBoard[col][row];
                    currentSquare.ContainsLetter = true;
                    currentSquare.Letter = letter;
                    currentSquare.partOfCurrentTurn = true;
                    theCurrentGame.TheBoard.ScrabbleBoard[col][row] = currentSquare;
                    drawBoard(theCurrentGame.TheBoard);
                    //remove tile from display
                    theCurrentGame.Human.TileRack.Tiles.Remove(letter);
                    currentTileSelected.Source = null;
                    currentTileSelected.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
                   currentTileSelected = null;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                currentTileSelected.Source = null;
                currentTileSelected.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
              currentTileSelected= null;
                redrawTileRack();
            }

        }
```

Could anyone help me as to why this may be happening, that the element gets dragged, but leaves a copy behind and then throws a null reference exception? Or maybe suggest a better, more reliable way of achieving this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone is wondering how I fixed this, I forgot to basically clear my canvas before I drew onto it again. All that was needed was to remove all the child elements before drawing them again.

I used a tool called [Snoop](http://snoopwpf.codeplex.com/), which showed me the different layers and then I managed to figure out what my code was doing.